# DevExpress Ribbon Customization Menu: Add commands to original group

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, customization, ribbon-control

I have a C# Visual Studio 2015 project and I added a DevExpress Ribbon control (v16.2.4) in my form and I set

`AllowCustomization = True`

How can I add commands through the Customization Form into original groups (not custom)?

[image]

I found this 
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11528
and it says:

**Task**: Add commands to custom page groups

**Action**: Select a group within the right ListBox and a command to be added within the left ListBox, and drag-and-drop or click the right arrow button (=>)

**Note: adding commands to the original page groups is not allowed by default.**

Is there a way to change this default behavior (stated at the "Note:..." line) and add commands to original page groups too?